# How to Check if a Matrix is in a List of Matrices Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

This is the list of matrices;

```py
[matrix([[1, 0],
         [1, 0],
         [1, 0],
         [1, 0]]),
 matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
 matrix([[0, 1],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 1]]),
 matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
 matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

and I want to check if a matrix is already inside the list example;

```py
a = matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

So if a is in m then print True else print False

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using NumPy. If this is the case, don't use `np.matrix`, use `np.array`. `np.matrix` exists almost exclusively for legacy reasons and has undesirable features.

You can use `any` with a generator comprehension and [`np.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html). This will short-circuit to `True` if the array is found in the input list, otherwise return `False`.

```
import numpy as np

L = [np.array([[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]),
     np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
     np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]),
     np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
     np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]])]

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]])

res = any(np.array_equal(A, i) for i in L)  # False
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting this "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fe874754aa0>"

Comment: Figured it out, the last line of code should be "res = any([np.array_equal(A, i) for i in L])"

Comment: No, `res = any(np.array_equal(A, i) for i in L)` should work fine. Using a list comprehension isn't recommended as it requires building a `list` first, which isn't necessary for this task.

Comment: The bad `any` output observed by the questioner is a symptom of using `from numpy import *`, or something else that hides the built-in `any` with `numpy.any`. This is one of the primary examples of why not to use star imports.